# How can i get a single response using linq

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have the following API code to get a single result response but i get error json.net complaining
when i remove this line `var Product = prdList .FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == productID);` and `return Json(prdList);` it works fine but return every row in a table. how can i get a single record?

Here is the code

```
[HttpGet("{productID}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Getproduct(int productID)
        {
            var prdList = (await rpsService.Getrps(productID)).ToList();
            var Product = prdList .FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == productID);
            return Json(Product);

        }
```

Here is the error im getting, i retrive the right information but i get error when i load the page

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1
>   Project name' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to
>   deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a
>   JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it
>   is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a
>   collection type like an array or List)  that can be deserialized
>   from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type
>   to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'productID', line
>   1, position 13.

I tried this working fine but display all rows

```
     [HttpGet("{productID}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetProduct(int productID)
        {
            var prdList = (await rpsService.Getrps(productID)).ToList();
           return Json(prdList );

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return everything"? is it a list of product or any other records form related tables ?

Comment: @RangaDewasinghe i mean every row in a table

Comment: 'Deserialize' implies the issue is in your code *calling* this API, where's that code? If it expects an array, did you mean do return `Where(a => a.ID == productID)` rather than `FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == productID)`?

Comment: @lan Mercer that what i wanted, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can directly apply condition while fetching list as mention below.

```
 var prdList = (await rpsService.Getrps(productID)).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` create the problem and whats the benefit of applying directly while fetching list as?

Comment: As i have seen you are already passing productid as an argument in Getrps to filter the data so your.  Also if FirstOrDefault() creating the problem then can you please check what is the return type of Getups(). Does it return a list/Enumerable or single object?

Comment: If return single object then no need to apply FirstOrDefault(). can you please share

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  var Product = prdList.Where(a => a.ID == productID).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
var prdList = (await rpsService.Getrps(productID)).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
           return Json(prdList);
```